# How can I programmatically set target_os in a unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, tdd

I tried the following approaches:

```rust
fn get_system_extension(&self) -> String {
    if cfg!(target_os = "windows") {
        String::from(".lib")
    } else {
        String::new()
    }
}

mod test {
    #[allow(unused_imports)]
    use super::*;

    use std::env;

    #[test]
    fn get_system_extension_one() -> Result<(), CcrustyError> {
        env::set_var("CARGO_BUILD_TARGET", "linux");

        let result = get_system_extension();

        assert_eq!(String::new(), result);

        Ok(())
    }

    #[test]
    fn get_system_extension_two() -> Result<(), CcrustyError> {
        env::set_var("CARGO_CFG_UNIX", "");

        let result = get_system_extension();

        assert_eq!(String::new(), result);

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html) those could be set in a file, but I have no clue how to dynamically link them to tests.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You want to target an OS that _isn't_ the one you are compiling for?

Comment: Actually, yes and no.

I want to to test both target in my tests without having to change the OS, might not be clear in the question itself

Comment: No, that's clear. What I don't understand is how you want to test OS-specific code  for two different OS while only building and running your code on one OS.

Comment: Also, I hope you've seen https://crates.io/crates/cc

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something something like:

```rust
#[test]
    fn currect_system_extension() -> Result<(), CcrustyError> {
        let system = env::var_os("CARGO_BUILD_TARGET");
        let result = get_system_extension();

        match system => {
             "linux" => assert_eq!(String::new(), result),
             "windows" => assert_eq!(".libs".to_string(), result),
             _ => (),
        }
        Ok(())
    }
```

Even with this you would have to compile both versions for this test to cover the code. take a look at using `--all-targets`

https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html